# The output is correct but the online judge wouldn't accept?

Tags: c

I had tried all the C compiler but keep getting wrong answer on test 1, even though i already try to use the input on test 1 and had received the correct output when I tried it on the DEV c++.

input:
5
0 1 0 1 1

output:
4

this is a case study, so basically 5 in the input means the amount of period.
0 means break time and 1 means study time. if input is 1 total hour of study hours would be added by one, if its 0 there will be no study hence study hours would not be added. there is also a special case, like shown in the input if previously she was studying and now she is having breaks but after the breaks she will have a class (1 0 1) the break will be counted as study time and so study hours will be ++.

any idea? is it the code perhaps?
(the accepted code)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int n,hours=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char str[n*2];
    int x[n];
    
    while ((getchar()) != '\n'); 
    
    fgets(str, n*2 , stdin); 
    
    char* piece = strtok(str, " ");
    for(int i=1; piece != NULL ; i++)
    {
        sscanf(piece, "%d" , &x[i]);
        piece = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    for(int i=0 ; i<n+1; i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            if(x[0]==1){
                hours++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(x[i]==0)
            {
                if( x[i-1]==1 && x[i+1]==1 )
                {
                    hours++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                hours++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",hours);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't said anything about what the input is, or what the output should be. We have no idea what these tests are. For that matter, why is this tagged basic? It's clearly about C... Side-note: Not checking returns from `scanf`, `sscanf`, `fgets`, etc. is a bad idea; when they fail, you'll have no idea anything is wrong and just keep on running with garbage.

Comment: Apart from the input and output it would make sense if you told us what problem the code is trying to solve.

Comment: just edited it, tbh this is my first time asking a question,I thought more tags the better, anyway noted and thank you.

Comment: Just describe the question in more details. Like what you are trying to achieve. What your algo. does .

Comment: and what about [ i-1 ] when i=0 in your loop?

Comment: @kelvin the output will still be correct though.

Comment: May be your garbage value fits in the equation

Comment: Please think about some other test cases, and try them. If you find no error, [edit] your question and show us these inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason the online judge do not accept the solution even though the answer is correct in other ide is either because you have extra indentation in your program or a loop doesn't terminate, or you get garbage value or you try incrementing a not defined value.

Comment: just added the input and output, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are using [ i-1 ] and when index is 0 in for some inputs you will get a garbage value. May be it will work for some inputs,and not for others.